# "cl-flet" macro not allowing for recursive functions

Tags: elisp-macros

I am used to the deprecated elisp macro `flet` and I was told to change to `cl-flet`.  However upon making this change some of my elisp programs stopped working and I realized the reason is that, unlike `flet`, `cl-flet` does not allow for recursive functions.  For example, defining the function below

```
(defun show-problem-in-action (x)
  (cl-flet (
    (factorial (n)
      (if (= n 0)
        1
        (* n (factorial (- n 1))) )))
  (factorial x) ))
```

one gets **no error** by calling

```
(show-problem-in-action 0)
```

Output: 1

because the "cl-flet-defined" function `factorial` does not call itself when "x=0".  However

```
(show-problem-in-action 5)
```

produces the error `void-function factorial`.

On the other hand, replacing `cl-flet` by its deprecated macro `flet`, such as below

```
(defun no-problem-with-deprecated-macro (x)
  (flet (
    (factorial (n)
      (if (= n 0)
        1
        (* n (factorial (- n 1))) )))
  (factorial x) ))
```

allows for recursive invocation:

```
(no-problem-with-deprecated-macro 5)
```

Output: 120

If `cl-flet` is not working, what would be my best alternative to replace `flet` with, still being able to call functions recursively?

Comment: BTW, the crucial difference between `flet` and `cl-flet` is not the lack of support for recursion but the fact that `flet` provides dynamically-scoped function definitions, whereas `cl-flet`provides lexically-scoped function definitions.  Dynamic scoping happens to provide support for recursion by virtue of relying internally on an indirection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `cl-labels` instead of `cl-flet`. For explanation look at the
[emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Function-Bindings.html)

Comment: Or indeed `C-h f cl-flet` which says "Like `cl-labels` but the definitions are not recursive."

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Wouldn't it be nice if the warning I got ('flet' is an obsolete macro (as of 24.3); use either 'cl-flet' or 'cl-letf') also mentioned 'cl-labels'?

Comment: I noticed (the hard way) that another difference between `flet` and `cl-labels` is that functions defined with the latter syntax **must** be referred to via the #' quotation, as opposed to the usual single-quote.

Comment: Despite the fact that my question got three up-votes so far, I am a bit embarrassed because it can be answered straight from the doc-string of `cl-labels`, as pointed out by @phils.  I'll be glad to delete it should anybody think it is using up unnecessary space in this forum.

Comment: @Ruy : no problem at all. I, for one, learned something from this exchange, and I doubt I’ll be the only one.

Comment: @Ruy please leave it up, this is the first Google result for "cl recursive flet" :) and your comment about `#'` is poignant.